# Generate a concatenation from two different row records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following line records in my Oracle database

```
TERM    CRN   SUBJ    CRSE    SCHD_CODE
2016    104   BIOL     252        B
2016    104   BIOL     252        L
2017    123   MATH     201        E
2017    123   MATH     201        S
```

Is it possible to generate an SQL statement to come up with a concatenation on “SCHD_CODE” field using group by like below sample ???

```
Select term, CRN, SUBJ, CRSE, (SCH_CODE||'/'|| SCH_CODE) from xx 
GROUP BY term, CRN, SUBJ, CRSE
```

need to have below desired output:

```
TERM       CRN     SUBJ    CRSE   SCHD_CODE
2016       104     BIOL     252     B/L
2017       123     MATH     201     E/S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try self join also:

```
select * from (
    select 
    case when table1.SCHD_CODE <> table2.SCHD_CODE then "" else NULL END as test,
    table1.TERM,table1.SUBJRN,table1.SUBJ,table1.CRSE,table1.SCHD_CODE, (table1.SCHD_CODE||'/'||table2.SCHD_CODE)
    from result table1
    join result table2 on table1.TERM=table2.TERM
    and table1.SUBJRN=table2.SUBJRN 
    and table1.SUBJ=table2.SUBJ
    and table1.CRSE=table2.CRSE) b where test is not null
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT term,
       CRN,
       SUBJ,
       CRSE,
       LISTAGG(SCHD_CODE, '/' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY schd_code ) AS schd_code
FROM   xx 
GROUP BY term, CRN, SUBJ, CRSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only need to `CONCAT` 2 rows, then simply use `MIN`, `MAX`.

Try this,

```
Select term, CRN, SUBJ, CRSE
    ,(MIN(SCH_CODE)||'/'|| MAX(SCH_CODE)) from xx 
GROUP BY term, CRN, SUBJ, CRSE
```